# INSERT with on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql

I'm having difficulty understanding the correct syntax for an insert with an on duplicate key update check.

I currently get an error with the query:

```
INSERT INTO users_items (q,id,uid)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
q = q + ?, id = ?, uid = ?
```

The unique key is `uid` + `id` together.

My error is:

```
 Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Comment: There should be more in the error message. It points to the actual issue

Comment: Where are the actual `VALUES` that you want to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VALUES` is the required part (or `SET` or `SELECT`)

```
INSERT INTO users_items (q,id,uid)
VALUES (v1, v2, v3) -- <<< this is what you missed
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
q = q + ?, id = ?, uid = ?
```

Referene:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: Ah i see although that kinda confuses me, because this query which i did at a different time works without it: http://www.paste.to/MjY3NDI=
Why is that?

Comment: @Dave: the latter one takes the data from another table. Where does the query from the question should take the data?

Comment: Your answer in this case worked for my question. I just wondered why i don't need "Values" in my paste.to example was all.

Comment: @Dave: Because you already have `SELECT`. Have you opened a link I gave in my answer? I did it with some intentions